# Preselect Options-value

Tags: angular

When I get `UI_IngridientUnits` async from my backend the preselection of `iu.Unit` doesn't work anymore.

It displays always the same value(HTML), even if on runtime(object), the values are different.

Here is my https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngy3ci?file=src/app/hello.component.ts.

(The important fact here: "`iu.Unit` must be strictly equal to one of the option's value", to be selected)

This is what I do, to fetch the data:

```
getIngridientUnits(filter) {
        return this._http.get(this.myAppUrl + 'Get' + '?' + this.toQueryString(filter))
            .pipe(map((res: IngridientUnit[]) => { return res; }));
    }
```

, and then I subscripe to it

```
this.service.getIngridientUnits(null).subscribe(
            (data) => {
                this.UI_IngridientUnits = data 
            }
        );
```

All the values are there(runtime), but on the view there is always the same wrong value selected.

Don't know, how to simulate that API call.

I tried to put my code into `ngOnChanges`, hoping that it will refresh, when the value later changes:

```
`ngOnChanges() {
    //this.UI_IngridientUnits.forEach

    // won't hit, hoped to change to the correct unit
    console.log('ngOnChanges');

    this.UI_IngridientUnits.forEach(i => {

      let tempU: Unit[] = this.UI_Units.filter(u => u.Id == i.Unit.Id);

      if (tempU.length > 0)
        i.Unit = tempU[0];
    });
  }
`
```

What can I do ?

Comment: using your SB, if we use the object with alpha-numeric IDs and use one of these IDs inside the `this.UI_IngridientUnits` object, the code works fine. How are you calling the api? can you include your service in the SB also

Comment: you get this behavior because `this.UI_IngridientUnits.forEach(i => {
 
         let tempU: Unit[] = this.UI_Units.filter(u => u.Id == i.Unit.Id);

         if (tempU.length > 0)
             i.Unit = tempU[0];
     });` is placed inside `ngOnInit` and that it value is not fetched/returned when `ngOnInit` is run... place this code inside `ngOnChanges`

Comment: @AkberIqbal updated my code